# How to uninstall Java version 1.4

Tags: windows-xp, java, uninstall, jdk

I would like to asks a question about how to uninstall my old version of java(1.4.2_06) if it is not shown in add/remove in control panel? I'm using windows xp. I already uninstalled all my java that are in version 1.4 and I installed a latest version of java which is the version 7 but still the installed version of java in my pc is version 1.4. I already tried to reboot my pc everytime that I install/unstall the java.

Pleaaase help me and thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the [Java Uninstall Tool for Windows](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml) :

> The Java Uninstall tool helps you improve your computer security by
>   simplifying the process of finding and uninstalling older versions of
>   Java. The Uninstall tool shows you a list of the Java versions on your
>   computer and then removes those that are out of date.
>
> **System Requirements**
>
> - Operating system: Windows (**XP**, Vista, Windows 7,
>     Windows 8)
> - Browsers: Firefox 3.6+, IE 7+, Chrome Java version:
> - Runs
>     with Java 6u10 and later versions.
> - Can remove Java versions **1.4.2** and
>     above.
>
> How do I access the Java Uninstall tool? The tool is available:
>
> - by loading the [Java Uninstall tool](https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp) web page
> - after Windows Java 7 installation. The uninstall tool features are integrated with the Java verification (Windows only).
>
> This tool cannot be downloaded and it can run only within the browser.

If the above doesn't work then try [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/):

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE). It can assist in repairing or removing Java
>   when other methods fail.
>
> [image]
>
> **Its most significant feature is the
>   JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and
>   registry keys associated with the JRE.**